# Python pandas pivot not uniqe index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that has date as an index and two columns number and category like the following

```
 
    number  category
date        
2015-01-02  6.44    a
2015-01-02  100.00  n
2015-01-02  NaN     a
2015-01-02  0.19    d
2015-01-02  25.00   m
2015-01-02  1.00    n
2015-01-05  455.00  d
2015-01-05  18.78   m
2015-01-05  9.85    s
```

what I would like to do is find the sum for 'numbers' for every 'category' and every month. I thought the best option would be to do a pivot table something like

```
 df.pivot(index='date', columns='category', values='number')
```

but I get an error since the date values are not unique.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want pivot_table instead of pivot

Note: Since date appears to be the index, I do a reset_index first

```
df.reset_index().pivot_table(index = "date",columns = "category", 
                            values = "number", aggfunc = "sum")
```

yields

```
category    a     d       m      n    s
date                    
2015-01-02  6.44  0.19    25.00  101  NaN
2015-01-05  NaN   455.00  18.78  NaN  9.85
```